# iOS applications for iPhone 4

Tags: macos

When I click on software to update to iOS 8 on my iPhone 4, it responds that my phone is updated with iOS 6.5. What do I do to get 7 &/or 8?

Answer (score 1):

For iPhone 4 the maximum iOS is 7

According to Apple, the oldest iPhone model to get iOS 8 will be the iPhone 4s.

To update the Apple iPhone 4 to iOS 7, iTunes version 11 must be installed on the computer prior to installing the update.